# How can I factor a polynomial $(x+1)^n+(x-1)^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

My problem is basically how do I find the roots of $(x+1)^n+(x-1)^n=0$

It is from an exercise list of my professor. I tried open it in a sum and all I got was

if n is odd, then $x=0$ is a root and I get something like $2x(x^{n-1}+ax^{n-3}+\cdots + 1)$ with their respective binomial coefficients.

And if n is even, then i got almost the same thing but without the $x$.

Comment: factor in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ I forgot saying haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write it so:
$$\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n=-1$$ and solve the equation $z^n=-1$ or
$$z^n=1\left(\cos\pi+i\sin\pi\right).$$